# How do I tell linux bash to ignore backticks?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, chef-infra

I'm writing a chef recipe that calls the `mysql` command and executes a query. The problem is that the query passed into this command can have backticks, and I have no control over that. EG I'll do something like this:

`execute "update_customer_segment_custom_condition_#{no_space_segment_name}" do
    action :run
    command "mysql --user=#{user} #{db_name} --execute="CALL someStoredProcedure(\"A String\", \"A QUERY CONTAINING BACKTICKS OVER WHICH I HAVE NO CONTROL THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED VERBATIM\");"
end`

but Bash always complains about the syntax because it tries to interpret the backticks and evaluate. How can I tell it to completely ignore that character?

FYI this is being called inside a chef `execute` block as a `command`, hence using # for variables.

Comment: Variables are prefixed with `$` in `bash`, not `#`.

Comment: That's Ruby code because the command is being assembled via Chef.

Comment: If dealing with raw Bash, I'd plan to use single quotes around the `--execute='...command...'` argument (and then there's no need to escape embedded double quotes (or back quotes, of course), but you do need to worry about getting single quotes to MySQL).  I'm not sure whether that's something you can change somewhere in the pipeline you're using to get to MySQL.

Comment: Yea after playing around with it more, making sure single quotes are around the command being executed seems to work. I'll have my coworkers review it in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use an `execute` resource in Chef instead of `bash`. That won't use bash and thus backticks have no special meaning.

EDIT:

To be more specific with the example resource you posted

```
execute "update_customer_segment_custom_condition_#{no_space_segment_name}" do
  command ['mysql', "--user=#{user}", db_name, '--execute="CALL someStoredProcedure(\"A String\", \"A QUERY CONTAINING BACKTICKS OVER WHICH I HAVE NO CONTROL THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED VERBATIM\");"']
end
```

The array form for `command` shuts off any processing by the shell.

Comment: Then bash isn't being invoked, it is just passed to a normal exec call via mixlib-shellout.

Comment: I suppose I could specify the interpreter and try one of those out instead.

Comment: No, that's already what you want. There is no need for bash when running a command like this. Are you actually seeing it try to evaluate backticks?

Comment: If I use irb on my mac and create a Mixlib::Shellout.new('echo `which ls`') I get back /bin/ls.  In other words, it interprets my backtics and executes them.  And if I echo $SHELL I get back /bin/bash.  So, it appears, at least on osx the mixlib-shellout *can* use bash.  Not sure exactly what governs when this will and will not happen.

Comment: Mixlib::ShellOut.new(['echo', '\`which ls\`']).tap{|a| a.run_command}.stdout == "\`which ls\`\n"

Comment: If you use the single string form, you get the standard shell expansion. If you use the array you get a true raw exec.

Comment: I already submitted my pull request but I'll try this out when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably because you build a string with ruby (I dont' know ruby) and then pass it into a shell execute with action run

This already has a problem as your double quotes terminate in middle string:

command "**mysql --user=#{user} #{db_name} --execute=**"CALL someStoredProcedure(\"A String\", \"A QUERY CONTAINING BACKTICKS OVER WHICH I HAVE NO CONTROL THAT NEEDS TO BE PASSED VERBATIM\");"

so I wonder if ruby does not give a syntax error here for the supplemental " at the end.

the string you want to generate looks (probably) like this:

```
mysql --user=#{user} #{db_name} --execute="CALL someStoredProcedure(\"A String\", \"A QUERY\");"
```

you need to generate it like that:

```
mysql --user=#{user} #{db_name} --execute='CALL someStoredProcedure("A String", "A QUERY");"
```

And the part with "A QUERY" you need to replace all occurences of `'` with `'\''` else you can still get a shell code injection.